# Find a doc _id in Meteor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm trying to remove an item from a list. However, I cannot do it using the following code:

```
lists.remove('TjhdAGmCbKB8wCiBg')
```

As described in other threads, but I get the error "undefined". How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is `lists` a `Collection`? If so, try `lists.remove({_id : 'YOURID'})`

Comment: Yeah Its a meteor collection , tried that and I get the same error , I've also tried lists.remove({Category: "Gamess" _id: "9HBAhffyoD2EmJ2T7"})

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by one of two issues:

1) You need to define `lists` globally if you are doing that in your JavaScript console

For example, if your code is

```
var lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
```

change it to

```
lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
```

The second possibility is that you use the same spelling used in its declaration, for example, if you use `Lists` to define it then `lists` won't work. In JavaScript all definitions are case sensitive.

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific in the question , I'm using google chrome and editing through the console available in inspect element , lists is defined as I'm using lists.insert etc to populate the list so not sure why its not working for remove

Comment: Oh I see, you meant the response. It will be removed but it wont give a response to say that. You have to use the callback to let you know for sure.

Comment: oh ok , so If i have a list called categories and I want to remove items from the list what code do i need to implement ? following the "getting started with meteorjs and javascript framwork" book and they havent covered that so far except for the remove I've been trying to use which is failing

Comment: What you're doing is right as long as the id you're using exists. The only reason it says undefined is that Collection.remove() doesn't return anything. If you check the lists after that you would notice an item is removed.